# ifelse with dates in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

Suppose I have these data:

```
df <- structure(list(end = structure(c(2932896, 2932896, 17434, 2932896, 
2932896, 2932896), class = "Date"), start = structure(c(15397, 
16847, 14249, 13801, 12101, 13360), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

> df
         end      start
1 9999-12-31 2012-02-27
2 9999-12-31 2016-02-16
3 2017-09-25 2009-01-05
4 9999-12-31 2007-10-15
5 9999-12-31 2003-02-18
6 9999-12-31 2006-07-31
```

I want to to create a third variable, `dur`, conditional on some statement:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(dur = if_else(end == "9999-12-31",
                       as.duration(today() - max("2012-01-01", start)),
                       as.duration(max(start, "2012-01-01") - end)
                       )
         )
```

which produces the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

I know some suggest to use `DT` instead of `ifelse` with dates, but I'd like to stay within the tidyverse.

## Update 1

Here, the column `dur` denotes the expected output:

```
| end           | start         | dur                       | code                                              |
|------------   |------------   |-------------------------- |-------------------------------------------------- |
| 9999-12-31    | 2012-02-27    | 207100800s (~6.56 years)  | as.duration(today()-ymd("2012-02-27"))            |
| 9999-12-31    | 2016-02-16    | 81820800s (~2.59 years)   | as.duration(today()-ymd("2016-02-16"))            |
| 2017-09-25    | 2009-01-05    | 180921600s (~5.73 years)  | as.duration(ymd("2017-09-25")-ymd("2012-01-01"))  |
| 9999-12-31    | 2007-10-15    | 212025600s (~6.72 years)  | as.duration(today()-ymd("2012-01-01"))            |
| 9999-12-31    | 2003-02-18    | 212025600s (~6.72 years)  | as.duration(today()-ymd("2012-01-01"))            |
| 9999-12-31    | 2006-07-31    | 212025600s (~6.72 years)  | as.duration(today()-ymd("2012-01-01"))            |
```

## Update 2

I followed some of the suggestions. The following:

```
df %>%
  mutate(dur = if_else(end == ymd("9999-12-31"),
                       as.duration(today() - max(ymd("2012-01-01"), start)),
                       as.duration(max(start, ymd("2012-01-01")) - end)
                       )
         )
```

produces:

```
         end      start                     dur
1 9999-12-31 2012-02-27 81820800s (~2.59 years)
2 9999-12-31 2016-02-16 81820800s (~2.59 years)
3 2017-09-25 2009-01-05 50716800s (~1.61 years)
4 9999-12-31 2007-10-15 81820800s (~2.59 years)
5 9999-12-31 2003-02-18 81820800s (~2.59 years)
6 9999-12-31 2006-07-31 81820800s (~2.59 years)
```

which is clearly not what I want.

## Update 3 (Solved!)

Thanks to [@jdobres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436545/jdobres) I had to use `pmax` instead of `max`.  The reason escapes me, but the documentation says: *pmax and pmin will also work on classed S3 or S4 objects with appropriate methods for comparison, is.na and rep (if recycling of arguments is needed)*. I suspect S4 objects has to do with this.

```
df %>%
  mutate(dur = if_else(end == ymd("9999-12-31"),
                       as.duration(today() - pmax(ymd("2012-01-01"), start)),
                       as.duration(pmax(start, ymd("2012-01-01")) - end)
                       )
         )
```

Produces:

```
         end      start                      dur
1 9999-12-31 2012-02-27 207100800s (~6.56 years)
2 9999-12-31 2016-02-16  81820800s (~2.59 years)
3 2017-09-25 2009-01-05 180921600s (~5.73 years)
4 9999-12-31 2007-10-15 212025600s (~6.72 years)
5 9999-12-31 2003-02-18 212025600s (~6.72 years)
6 9999-12-31 2006-07-31 212025600s (~6.72 years)
```

Comment: Can you add your expected output ?

Comment: I think `2012-01-01` just needs to be a date `as.Date("2012-01-01")`, not a character.

Comment: What other non-base R packages are you using? `dplyr` is safe, are you also using `lubridate`? Please be explicit about them (until they are installed in base R :-).

Comment: `max( as.Date(2932896, origin="1970-01-01") ,  "9999-12-31")` returns NA. Just because `==` has been defined to operate with character values that can be coerced to Dates, does not mean that `max` has similar capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you convert your date strings to Date data with `ymd` or `as.Date`, you can use `pmax` to get the larger of the two durations. `pmax` gives you the parallel maximum across vectors with the same number of elements. For example:

```
 pmax(1:10, rep(5, 10))

 [1]  5  5  5  5  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

The code would look like:

```
df %>%
  mutate(dur = if_else(end == ymd("9999-12-31"),
                       as.duration(today() - pmax(ymd("2012-01-01"), start)),
                       as.duration(pmax(start, ymd("2012-01-01")) - end)
                       )
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do a mutate, like you did, after using `lubridate::ymd()` on the character dates that you entered, but the `max()` didn't compare on a row-by-row basis, but grabbed the max of all start values - maybe someone can explain why?

I ended up going with apply.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(dur =
           apply(tbl_df(df), 1, function(x){
             print(x)

             ifelse(
               x["end"] == ymd("9999-12-31"),

               interval(today(), max(ymd("2012-01-01"), ymd(x["start"]))) %>%
                 as.duration() %>%
                 as.numeric("years"),

               interval(max(x["start"], ymd("2012-01-01")), ymd(x["end"])) %>%
                 as.duration() %>%
                 as.numeric("years")
             )

           }))

#          end      start       dur
# 1 9999-12-31 2012-02-27 -6.562628
# 2 9999-12-31 2016-02-16 -2.592745
# 3 2017-09-25 2009-01-05  8.720055
# 4 9999-12-31 2007-10-15 -6.718686
# 5 9999-12-31 2003-02-18 -6.718686
# 6 9999-12-31 2006-07-31 -6.718686
```

Even though the start and end values were already date format, I needed to use `ymd()` again in the function. I've noticed this before and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Even switching between the more rigorous `if_else` and the looser `ifesle` didn't help.

Comment: `pmax` in place of `max` should do it.